# Different port bandwidth on switch causing massive bandwidth loss?

Tags: networking, switch, bandwidth

i think i am missing some basic knowledge about network connectivity, maybe someone out there could explain me, why the following causes problems. The facts:

- We are connected to the "internet" with 100mbit/s, full duplex.
- We had the cable of our internet provider connected to a security appliance (Cisco ASA): outside- *and* inside-port where configured to both 100mbit/s, full duplex.
- Behind the security appliance we had a 24-port 10/100/1000mbit/s switch. The port connected to the ASA was configured to be 100mbit/s, full-duplex ... the other ports where configured to be 1000mbit/s

Internal bandwidth between the machines connected to the switch was always very good. Incoming bandwidth was always *ok*. Outgoing bandwidth was *ok* until after two years suddenly the outgoing bandwidth dropped down to below 1mbit/s.

At first we thought we had a problem with our ASA, because we detected lot's of CRC errors on the outside-port of the appliance. We swapped the hardware, but the bandwidth problem was not solved.

We than changed the configuration of the inside-port of the ASA to 1000mbit/s, full duplex and the port of the switch to 1000mbit/s, too ... so that every port of the switch now has 1000mbit/s.

This not only solved our bandwidth problem, it's even better than before. Apparently we had some kind of bandwidth-mismatch because of the different configuration in the switch ... but i am not really sure, why ... is there some "easy" explanation for this kind of problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is exactly as you describe so I am not sure exactly what you are looking for an answer.

You have a duplex mismatch.

More information:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplex_mismatch

Comment: Thanks, i think i wanted to know the opinion of someone who would have probably more knowledge than me about all this. Btw.: i found netperf to be an excellent tool to debug such bottlenecks.

Comment: Edit: I get it now; setting the mode on only some of the ports caused other devices connected to those ports to fail auto-negotiation and fall-back to half-duplex mode.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb I always MANUALLY set every port to be at its maximum speed, I know it's a contentious issue around here but I don't trust auto-speed/duplex detection. I can't comment on you exact situation without further information but I suspect there was a port speed issue and also that perhaps your ASA is doing some form of caching perhaps that, when set to GigE allowed for this performance increase. Well done either way.